# Xubuntu 12.04 display (with bumblebee) screwed up after upgrade

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, optimus

I recently left my machine (running Xubuntu 12.04) up while it upgraded some 300 different things.  I have a Hybrid Graphics NVIDIA Optimus system, and it was working perfectly with Bumblebee 3.0 up until the upgrade.  Since the upgrade, fonts don't render correctly (certain pixels in white letters turn black) and Bumblebee throws

```
[430.015513] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[430.015627] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

when I try to run anything with the NVIDIA chip.

I googled the errors and a reboot seems to have fixed it for most.  I've rebooted, re-installed bumblebee, and updated my nvidia drivers, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been getting the exact same issue and managed to get this working after ignoring it for a while. I'm also running 12.04 based Mint 13 64 bit LTS using backported packages and the ubuntu-xswat-ppa. My laptop is using the Nvidia 310M Optimus hybrid graphics (ASUS U43jc) - here's what I did to resolve:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo apt-get build-dep nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install bumblebee --reinstall
```

After that checked the service status and finally running! Tried running:

```
optirun glxspheres
```

which ran successfully averaging ~106 frames/sec and ~99 Mpixels/sec at 1920x1080 on my external display.

Good luck!